# When is a PDE a subbundle of a jet bundle (as opposed to a fibered submanifold or just a closed embedded submanifold)?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, smooth-manifolds, fiber-bundles, jet-bundles

Nowadays it is common to see PDEs defined as either closed embedded submanifolds of a jet bundle (of some appropriate order) or else, if some further conditions are satisfied, as a fibered submanifold.  In some earlier literature, though (e.g., Quillen's dissertation), a PDE is defined as a *subbundle* of a jet bundle.  That strikes me as a strong restriction, but I don't immediately see how strong.  I presume it is related to whether solutions exist.

Is anyone aware of good resources discussing when a PDE is a subbundle, rather than a fibered submanifold?  Are there easy-to-check conditions on the equation defining the submanifold that ensure this?